# How to use Angular-fullstack without server components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I really like the way Angular-Fullstack scaffolds the project. But I already have data served through a restful API. So I don't need any server components. Is there a way, I can only use the client part and remove the server components ?

Update: I am aware of generator-Angular scaffolding but I would like the way Fullstack scaffolds.

Thanks.

Comment: how about the opposite? using angular-fullstack without the client-side stuff?

Answer (score 3):

Using [angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) would be a better choice. It only deals with the front-end (such as your case).

**Update**

The guys behind angular-fullstack already started part of the de-coupling. check [ng-component generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-ng-component).

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, but it doesn't scaffold the way angular-fullstack client. So was curious if there is a way you know of to remove the server components ?